# Eliminate duplicates and retrieve Max Value for each ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
ID     Signal    Station    Owner
111     -120      Home      M1
111     -120      Home      M1
111     -120      Home      M2
111     -120      Car       M1
111     -120      Car       M2
111     -120      Work      M1
111    -120       Dept      M3
111     -130      Car       M1
111     -135      Work      M2
222     -98       Home      M2
222     -95       Work      M1
222     -103      Work      M2
```

I just need the Query to return the max signal for each ID:If Signal is equal display one in random.But the below query is returning duplicates if the Signal is the same for multiple Stations and owners. Please help me out on this.All the fields are in same table

```
ID    Signal    Station    Owner
111    -120       Dept        M3       
111    -120       Home        M1      
111    -120       Work        M2      
222    -95        Work        M1
```

But i need with out duplicate entries

```
Here is the SQL:

SELECT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, g.Station, g.OwnerID FROM (SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS  
MaxSignal FROM t GROUP BY id) AS g inner join t ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal;
```

Comment: Do you have any other column in this table that makes a row unique? Primary key maybe?

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT` right after your `SELECT`

Comment: Added back quotes around Signal because Signal is a reserved word used primarily in Stored Procedures.

Comment: I answered this question already : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8811830/491757

Comment: I answered this question already : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8811830/491757

Comment: I changed the query in my answer and added your additional row. The new query works. Try it now !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM
(SELECT ID,`Signal`,MIN(CONCAT(Station,'-',Owner)) MaxStationOwner
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM  
(SELECT ID,MAX(`Signal`) `Signal` FROM t GROUP BY ID) AAA 
LEFT JOIN t USING (ID,`Signal`)) AA
GROUP BY ID,`Signal`) A
INNER JOIN t B
ON A.MaxStationOwner=CONCAT(B.Station,'-',B.Owner)
AND A.ID=B.ID AND A.`Signal`=B.`Signal`;
```

Here is your sample data:

```
drop database if exists preeti; 
create database preeti; 
use preeti 
create table t  
(ID int not null,  
`Signal` int not null,  
Station varchar(10),  
Owner varchar(10));  
insert into t values  
(111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M1' ),
(111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M1' ),
(111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M2' ),
(111,     -120 ,     'Car'  , 'M1' ),
(111,     -120 ,     'Car'  , 'M2' ),
(111,     -120 ,     'Work' , 'M1' ),
(111,    -120  ,     'Dept' , 'M3' ),
(111,     -130 ,     'Car'  , 'M1' ),
(111,     -135 ,     'Work' , 'M2' ),
(222,     -98  ,     'Home' , 'M2' ),
(222,     -95  ,     'Work' , 'M1' ),
(222,     -103 ,     'Work' , 'M2' );
```

Here is your sample data loaded:

```
mysql> drop database if exists preeti;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create database preeti;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use preeti
Database changed
mysql> create table t
    -> (ID int not null,
    -> `Signal` int not null,
    -> Station varchar(10),
    -> Owner varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into t values
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M1' ),
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M1' ),
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Home' , 'M2' ),
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Car'  , 'M1' ),
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Car'  , 'M2' ),
    -> (111,     -120 ,     'Work' , 'M1' ),
    -> (111,    -120  ,     'Dept' , 'M3' ),
    -> (111,     -130 ,     'Car'  , 'M1' ),
    -> (111,     -135 ,     'Work' , 'M2' ),
    -> (222,     -98  ,     'Home' , 'M2' ),
    -> (222,     -95  ,     'Work' , 'M1' ),
    -> (222,     -103 ,     'Work' , 'M2' );
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM
    -> (SELECT ID,`Signal`,MIN(CONCAT(Station,'-',Owner)) MaxStationOwner
    -> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM
    -> (SELECT ID,MAX(`Signal`) `Signal` FROM t GROUP BY ID) AAA
    -> LEFT JOIN t USING (ID,`Signal`)) AA
    -> GROUP BY ID,`Signal`) A
    -> INNER JOIN t B
    -> ON A.MaxStationOwner=CONCAT(B.Station,'-',B.Owner)
    -> AND A.ID=B.ID AND A.`Signal`=B.`Signal`;
+-----+--------+---------+-------+
| ID  | Signal | Station | Owner |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+
| 111 |   -120 | Car     | M1    |
| 222 |    -95 | Work    | M1    |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Make sure you have this index on table t:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD INDEX ID_Signal_Index (ID,`Signal`);
```

Comment: Added one more column insert into t values(111,-120,'Home',2)
Duplicate still there

Comment: I want owner as varchar instead of ownerid.I am getting the output as duplicates:ID     Signal     Station     Owner    
     -----  ---------  ----------  -------- 
     111    -120       Home        M1      
     111    -120       Work        M2      
     222    -95        Work        M1

Comment: I cannot do that because you did not tell me the what the table `t` looks like. You did not tell me if there was an Owner field in the same table or an outside table. Please specify that in your question.

Comment: I changed everything in my answer to accommodate your new data layout

Comment: Thanks and i appreciate for your response.If i have another varchar column in the same table can i do the same way by using concat

Answer (score 0):

i think you can just use:

```
SELECT `ID`, MAX(`Signal`), `Station`, `OwnerID` FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `ID`
```

instead of your query

Comment: Correct. Note that `Station` and `OwnerID` _will_ be unspecified (within the `ID` grouping) and I don't think that they even have to come from the same row as each other.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: right - `The server is free to choose any value from each group`, he wanted some randomness :) and i backticked column names, because `signal` is a keyword

Comment: This doesn't work.we will get the max(signal) but will not give exact values for the remaining column will pick in random.I need the corresponding values for the max(Signal)

Comment: @preeti: Your question says you wanted random ones. You can't get the real ones without doing a separate lookup.

Comment: SELECT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, t.Station, t.OwnerID FROM (SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS MaxSignal FROM t GROUP BY id) AS g inner join t ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal; This query will retrieve the exact rows for the maxsignal..but retrieving duplicates if signal values are equal.. i want one in random

Comment: @preeti: And why are you showing us that again? Care to leave a sentence with it?

Comment: I didn't get you.seperate look up means?

Comment: Any help how to get rid of duplicates will be appreciated.

Comment: i have been trying to solve it for almost an hour, but didn't get anything better right now :) i'm satisfied by `group by` in my queries i think :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting distinct after the first select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, t.Station, t.OwnerID 
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS  MaxSignal 
    FROM t 
    GROUP BY id
) AS g 
INNER JOIN t ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal;
```

This works with the example data shown, but would not work where rows have the same ID and (max) Signal but with different values for Station or Owner or both. In SQL Server I would get round the problem by using the ROW_COUNT function (is there an equivalent function in mysql?):

```
SELECT Id, MaxSignal, Station, OwnerID
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        g.ID, 
        g.MaxSignal, 
        t.Station, 
        t.OwnerID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.ID, g,MaxSignal ORDER BY t.Station) AS RowNumber
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS  MaxSignal 
        FROM t 
        GROUP BY id
    ) AS g 
    INNER JOIN t ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal
) AS T1
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: distinct will work if both rows are equal if i have added another column.                                                                  111    -120       Car         1

Comment: If there isn't a ROW_COUNT equivalent in mysql then you could achieve the required result by using a correlated sub query on the right side of the INNER JOIN that selects the TOP 1 row from t where MaxSignal and id are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, t.Station, t.OwnerID 
FROM (SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS MaxSignal 
      FROM t 
      GROUP BY id) AS g 
    INNER JOIN t 
        ON g.id = t.id 
             AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal;
```

Comment: operand distinct should contain only one column